# Keep getting error: [E::fai_build3_core] Failed to open the file --regions for a script I have been using

Tags: linux, bash, bioinformatics

I have been using the below script however, I keep getting an error on the output. Any ideas why?

```
#!/bin/bash

set - eu

bam_input=$3

geome=/storage1/DISK1/TCGA_scripts/ref_genome/GRCh38.ref.fa
export genome




function bam_chromosomes {
        samtools idxstats $bam_input | cut -f 1 | grep -v '*'
}

export -f bam_chromosomes




function parallel_call {
    bcftools mpileup \
        --fasta-ref ${genome} \
        --regions $2 \
        --output-type u \
        $1 | \
    bcftools call --multiallelic-caller \
                  --variants-only \
                  --output-type u - > ${1/.bam/}.$2.bcf
}

export -f parallel_call


chrom_set=`bam_chromosomes test.bam`
parallel --verbose -j 90% parallel_call sample_A.bam ::: ${chrom_set}
```

The above script is the first step in parallelizing the process mpileup which should calculate variants within a .bam file. The following error keeps ocuring:

```
parallel_call sample_A.bam 'Usage:'
parallel_call sample_A.bam samtools
parallel_call sample_A.bam idxstats
parallel_call sample_A.bam '[options]'
Note: none of --samples-file, --ploidy or --ploidy-file given, assuming all sites are     diploid
[E::fai_build3_core] Failed to open the file --regions
Failed to open -: unknown file type
parallel_call sample_A.bam '<in.bam>'
Note: none of --samples-file, --ploidy or --ploidy-file given, assuming all sites are   diploid
[E::fai_build3_core] Failed to open the file --regions
Failed to open -: unknown file type
Note: none of --samples-file, --ploidy or --ploidy-file given, assuming all sites are   diploid
[E::fai_build3_core] Failed to open the file --regions
Failed to open -: unknown file type
parallel_call sample_A.bam --input-fmt-option
parallel_call sample_A.bam 'OPT[=VAL]'
Note: none of --samples-file, --ploidy or --ploidy-file given, assuming all sites are  diploid
[E::fai_build3_core] Failed to open the file --regions
Failed to open -: unknown file type
parallel_call sample_A.bam Specify
parallel_call sample_A.bam a
Note: none of --samples-file, --ploidy or --ploidy-file given, assuming all sites are diploid
[E::fai_build3_core] Failed to open the file --regions
```

In theory the above script should create a number of files with the variable substitution ${1/.bam/}.$2.bcf which avoids filename collision. It's difficult for me to upload any of the files as they are very large and my internet speed is very slow. Thanks for any help.

Comment: a) Check typo: geome vs genome, b) add `set -x` to parallel_call to see how the programs are actually called. `$2` is likely empty, my hunch being that `chrom_set` is not set, c) ALWAYS enclose ALL variable references with `$` in double quotes, like `"${chrom_set}"`, except you know what you are doing.

Comment: looks like an invalid `samtools idxstats` call is generating a 'Usage' message (`Usage: samtools idxstats '[options]' Note: none of --samples-file, --ploidy or --ploidy-file given, assuming all sites are ...`) , which is being stored in the the `chrom_set` variaable (after set and before `parallel` call add `typeset -p chrom_set` to see contents of variable), which is then being fed to the follow-on `parallel/bcftools` call, and because the lengthy 'Usage' message is not a valid argument you're receiving this output; looks like first should be fixing the `samtools idxstats` call  ...

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.

Comment: Thanks, yep in the end i needed to a) correct the genome spelling and b) specify the .bam file to be acted upon when calling the script. i.e. test_script.sh test.bam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting to replace line:

```
 geome=/storage1/DISK1/TCGA_scripts/ref_genome/GRCh38.ref.fa
```

With line:

```
 genome=/storage1/DISK1/TCGA_scripts/ref_genome/GRCh38.ref.fa
```